# WPF window gets minimized instantly

Tags: c#, wpf, c++-cli

**SOLUTION** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10299856/1256811)

I was asked to emulate a windows forms context menu using a WPF window. I created a window when the user clicked a certain region, but that window got minimized to the task bar instantly. I need it to stay on top of other windows at least until it loses focus or is deactivated. Its window style is none, and it doesn't matter whether its show in taskbar property is true or false. Similar questions exist on SO, but they don't seem to solve anything in my case. Why this odd behavior? Is there a fix for it?

```
<Window x:Class="InterceptRouteWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  Width="200" ResizeMode="NoResize" SizeToContent="Height" ShowInTaskbar="False" Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStyle="None" Height="auto" Deactivated="Window_Deactivated">


        <StackPanel Height="auto" Name="stackPanel1" Width="200" Background="WhiteSmoke">
             <Separator Height="5"  FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
               <Separator.Background>
                 <SolidColorBrush />
               </Separator.Background>
            </Separator>
      </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

So it's a simple window. The way I invoke it:

```
 IRWindow = gcnew InterceptRouteWindow(routes, fpId, offsetPoint.x, offsetPoint.y);
 GetMainFrame()->IRWindow->Show();
```

This is triggered by a click event inside an older app, a mixture of MFC and WindowsForms.. not my code, I had to obey their design and use WPF where I could.

Comment: We need more data in order to be able to help...

Comment: Do you need to to sort Windows by z-index?

Comment: When the window is first created (via the gcnew) and shown, it's immediately deactivated, loses focus and the z-index is quite low. So I presume sorting it by the z will not help that much since its focus is "lost".. or would it, I'm not at all sure!?

Comment: do a binary search for your problem by deleting half your custom property values. if the problem persists, delete half of the remainders. if the problem goes away; then you've narrowed down your problem area.