# Receiving touch events outside window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How I can receiving touch events outside window in WPF?
With mouse I can use that:

```
System.Windows.Input.Mouse.Capture(this, System.Windows.Input.CaptureMode.SubTree);
```

I need same behavior like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299856/wpf-intercept-clicks-outside-a-modal-window)  but for touch

Comment: Please elaborate on your question a bit more. Explain what you're trying to do and what you've found in your research into the problem.

Comment: How about [TouchDevice.Capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd989302(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I want close dialog window when I tap outside it

Comment: @Clemens I cant understand how I can use this, i try: `e.TouchDevice.Capture(this, System.Windows.Input.CaptureMode.SubTree);` on Window_TouchUp but when I tapping outside from this window event not coming

Comment: You would usually capture a touch inside the element during the TouchDown event. No idea how touching outside would work.

Comment: @Clemens This is common action for many apps to close pop up window by tap on area outside it. For exapmle open and close photo on facebook.

Comment: They may have a transparent overlay that receives touch input, or the underlying elements close the dialog window. You may also try the [Touch.FrameReported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.touch(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: @Clemens ok thx, I try do this with common window (not dialog)